# How to remove blank line from index of a Dataframe while printing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, printing

I had a dataframe wherein there were several values of 'adani' and I grouped them by security used sum() funtion to get the below output. There are several more values below it.

There is an odd blank lines generated above security and below Notional while they both are column headers. Security now being the Index name. How to remove the 2 blank cell lines?

sample of my output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried strip() function? This should work
Assuming col as your column name:

```
dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].str.strip()
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, just to give more info... the 'Security' is the index name and 'Notional' is the column name... Both striped, but the alignment problem remains. This happened with every DF that I made by groupby() function.

Also, When I do reset_index(), the alignment problem is solved but it adds numbered index
Doing reset_index().set_index('Security') results in the same DF with allignment issue